# Why is git mentioning an Untracked file outside my current directory?

Tags: git

git is tracking a bunch of files:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
100644 blob a-sha1  .gitignore
100644 blob b-sha1  my/file
```

however when I do a `git status` I get:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ../../../.project
```

Why is `../../../.project` being listed as an untracked file?

Comment: Because the `.git` data directory is a few levels up. `ls ../../../.git`

Comment: Related: `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and `git rev-parse --show-cdup`. (Think of the last as "cd up", as in "cd ../../" etc, not as "c dup".)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't run `git init` in this repo, that can happen.
I added a `../` in *.gitignore* and then run `git init`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be due to it being present inside the directory where your git repository is initialized.

To stop it being tracked you could add that directory to your .gitignore